# Get random locale with python Faker lib

Tags: python, faker

Not sure if this exist or not, is it possible to generate random locales with python Faker lib? (https://faker.readthedocs.io/).

Good to have: generate supported locales

Comment: Looking at the docs: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/locales.html

Comment: This is different, I want to generate random locales, from supported locales.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. `faker.config.AVAILABLE_LOCALES` will give you all available locales. If you want just the locale - use random.choice. If you want random entry for some locale - use multi locale mode and there are number of random functions like `Faker.random_object_name`.

Comment: yes, I end up by using random.choices, I was just wondering if Faker provides this or not.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround:

```
>>> fake = Faker(["fr_FR", "it_IT", "de_DE"])
>>> fake.locales
['fr_FR', 'it_IT', 'de_DE']
>>> import random
>>> random.choices(fake.locales)[0]
de_DE
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it can. I had read the complete `faker` documentation for another study earlier, and never found any way to generate any locales.

Comment: yes I believe too, I use a simple random.choices for now, maybe write a plugin later!